# Layout support for ncurses?

Tags: c, layout, ncurses

As far as I know there is no such thing as a layout in ncurses however I am wondering if there isn't a third party extension which allows that.

I'm looking for support for the typical layouts such as horizontal, vertical and grid. Of course being able to automatically resize the "children" of a layout is a plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no - the space available for characters is usually small enough that no one bothers with more than a few choices in fixed-layouts.  Some applications resize, but use simple schemes for layout, e.g., all of the screen, half, etc.